# Pandas Dataframe=¿Porqué .set_index o .reindex no hacen absolutamente nada?

Tags: pandas, sqlite3, python-3.8

Estoy convirtiendo una tabla sql en un DataFrame. Es una tabla con las siguientes columnas: Año,Mes,Dia,Prec,Tmax,Tmin

```
import sqlite3 as sq
import pandas as pd
import datetime

conn= sq.connect('example.db')
c=conn.cursor()
a='SELECT * FROM ocba'
c.execute(a)
sql_file=c.fetchall()
file=pd.DataFrame(sql_file)  #Acá convierto la tabla a DataFrame
```

Luego creo una séptima columna con las fechas y lo agrego al DataFrame:

```
fechai=datetime.date(year=file[0][0],month=file[1][0],day=file[2][0])
z=len(file)-1
fechaf=datetime.date(year=file[0][z],month=file[1][z],day=file[2][z])
fechas=pd.date_range(start=fechai,end=fechaf)
file['Fecha']=(fechas)
```

Luego trato de establecer esa séptima columna como el índice, mediante .set_index o .reindex, y el método no hace absolutamente nada:

```
file.set_index('Fecha')
print(file)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Me imprime el mismo DataFrame

```
          0   1   2     3     4     5      Fecha
0      1908   1   1   0.0   NaN   NaN 1908-01-01
1      1908   1   2   0.0   NaN   NaN 1908-01-02
2      1908   1   3   0.0   NaN   NaN 1908-01-03
3      1908   1   4   0.0   NaN   NaN 1908-01-04
4      1908   1   5   0.0   NaN   NaN 1908-01-05
...     ...  ..  ..   ...   ...   ...        ...
40903  2019  12  27   0.0  33.3  20.4 2019-12-27
40904  2019  12  28   7.0  30.9  24.5 2019-12-28
40905  2019  12  29   0.7  34.3  22.4 2019-12-29
40906  2019  12  30  51.0  26.3  22.2 2019-12-30
40907  2019  12  31   0.0  28.5  21.4 2019-12-31

[40908 rows x 7 columns]
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Que pasa si haces `print(file.set_index('Fecha')) ` ?

Comment: Si asigno file.set_index('Fecha') a una nueva variable, y la imprimo, me sale tal cual quiero! Gracias!!

Comment: Como en la documentación hacen los cambios al DataFrame, y luego lo imprimen y sale el DataFrame con los cambios hechos. No sabía que había que asignarlo a una nueva variable. Tendré que leer más detenidamente.

Comment: Eso es por que lleva un parametro `inplace=False` (por defecto), solo tienes que ponerle `inplace=True` para hacerlo "inplace". o sino, solo asignarlo a una variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente!